# PHPExcel read csv - delimiter is semicolon - value has a semicolon

Tags: php, excel, phpexcel

I read a csv with PHPExcel. The CSV is seperated by `;`.

In my code i set:

```
$classPhpExcelCreateReader->setDelimiter(";");
```

It works fine. But some values has a semicolon and make problems.

Example:

```
text1;text2;te;xt3;text4
```

I can't get `text3` i get `te` and `xt3`

How can i fix it? Is there a solution in PHPExcel?

regards
ebody

Comment: does the csv have  enclosure characters

Comment: Unless values with `;` are quoted how would you know the difference between an embedded `;` and the delimiter?  Seems like your file is badly-formatted if it really looks like your posted example

Comment: If a value contains the delimiter and isn't enclosed, then it isn't a valid csv file.... `text1;text2;te;xt3;text4` should be something like `text1;text2;"te;xt3";text4` for it to be valid..... and no, PHPExcel doesn't have any magic solution for an invalid csv file, the solution is to fix it at source

Comment: garbage-in, garbage-out. How can you tell the difference between `te;xt3;text4` splitting into  `te`/`xt3;text4` or `te;xt3`/`text4`? Both are equally valid. You should fix whatever's generating the CSV in the first place, instead of trying to correct what it's spitting out.

Comment: Thanks for your help. It wasn´t a valid csv file.